# How can ejecting an audio CD by using cdaudio's cd_eject () method produce errno #5?

Tags: ioctl

I'm trying to playback an audio CD from my app by using the `cdaudio` library + a USB DVD drive attached to a Raspi 3B. Trying to eject the CD after playback **always** makes me end up with errno #5. This is my code:

```cpp
void sound::Eject ()
{
  struct disc_status cd_stat;

  if (sound::current_sound_source == CD) {
    sound::Stop ();
    cd_poll (sound::cd_drive_handler, &cd_stat);

    if (sound::is_cd_stopped && cd_stat.status_present == 1) {
      if ((cd_eject (sound::cd_drive_handler)) < 0) cout << "Ejecting CD failed! Error: " << strerror (errno) << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

This is the output I get:

```
ioctl returned -1
Ejecting CD failed! Error: Input/output error
```

When trying to eject the CD, I hear a noise in the drive, as if it was about to access the CD, for about half a second. This is the drive I'm using:

```
pi@autoradio:~ $ ls -al /dev/sr*
brw-rw----+ 1 root cdrom 11, 0 Mai  1 21:38 /dev/sr0
```

Ejecting the CD from the command line (`eject /dev/sr0`), does work, though.

Does anybody know what may cause this error? Thank you.

**UPDATE #1:** I gave `cdcd` (the command-line tool for audio CDs) a try, and I could reproduce the error there, too (even under `sudo`):

```
cdcd> eject
ioctl returned -1
```

**UPDATE #2:** I found out that `cdaudio` calls `ioctl` with the `CDAUDIO_EJECT` command (see [sourcecode](https://sourceforge.net/p/libcdaudio/libcdaudio/ci/master/tree/src/cdaudio.c#l492)), but I can't find such a command  anywhere in the [linux/cdrom.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/cdrom.h) file. *According to [one of the developers of the cdaudio library](https://sourceforge.net/p/libcdaudio/bugs/8/)*, this is just an alias for `CDROMEJECT` and not a bug.

**UPDATE #3:** `strace` give me this output. I hope this is sufficient:

```c
ioctl(3, CDROM_DISC_STATUS, 0)          = 100
ioctl(3, CDROMSUBCHNL, 0x7e93e308)      = 0
ioctl(3, CDROMEJECT, 0x1)               = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
write(1, "ioctl returned -1\n", 18)     = 18
```

In contrast, when tracing the `eject` utility, I get something slightly different:

```c
geteuid32()                             = 1000
open("/dev/sr0", O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)     = 3
ioctl(3, CDROMEJECT, 0x1)               = 0
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

A comparison of the `open ()` calls reveals that the `cdaudio` library apparently opens the drive on read-only mode (which is theoretically correct, but, on the other hand, seems to choke the `eject` command):

```c
open("/dev/sr0", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK)   = 3
```

**SEE ALSO:** Question [#26240195](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26240195/input-output-error-in-ejecting-cd-rom-from-c-code)

Comment: Anything in your system logs?

Comment: Nope! I found nothing.

Comment: You might like to use `strace` to see what `eject` and your code are doing differently.

Comment: Thnka you for your hint. See the updates on my question for what I've found out.

Comment: So, if you change your code to open the device read/write, does it work?

Comment: Well, I can't change the code of `cdaudio` myself, but as `eject` is using the read-write version (if the drive is a recorder, of course), this must be the solution.

Comment: I've patched and recompiled `cdaudio`, but the problem still persists, even if I call the `cdcd` frontend with the `eject` command given on the shell prompt.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after a couple of weeks of studying the `eject` utility, I found out that at least some CD drives wouldn't accept a `CDROMEJECT` command via `ioctl ()`, but require a bunch of SCSI commands. In fact, `eject` contains a method, which is used as a fallback in such situations: [`eject_scsi ()`](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/sys-utils/eject.c#L570). I implanted this method into `cdaudio`. Tests were successful. So I asked the maintainers of `cdaudio` for a respective [patch.](https://sourceforge.net/p/libcdaudio/patches/7/)